# force Innodb to recreate ib_logfile with mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, innodb

I got this error when changing the setting below

error:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file /bdd/ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 10485760 bytes than specified in the .cnf file 0 20971520 bytes!
```

Settings changed:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 256M >changed to 356mb
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 40M
innodb_log_file_size            = 10M >changed to 20mb
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
```

I know that i need to delete ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1, but I cant find them in my ftp directory (/bdd/ib_logfile0 this bdd directory, i cant find it), i see only my.cnf and mysql.err files and "dump" folder
i have phpmyadmin root account and ftp user for the files mentioned above, so there is a way to set different folder where save ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files, or delete them from phpmyadmin or a setting to force recreate them with new settings from my.cnf?

if I drop all databases the log files will disappear and then I can change the setting without getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I can't find any way to do this with sql 5.5, I upgraded to 5.7 which recreates files "ib_logfile1 and 2" automatically

Comment: That's a good answer.  Otherwise, I would say "dup of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/4103#4103 "